# Route localization in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I am developing an online store using ASP.NET Core 2 and I am struggling with how to implement route localization, ex. depending from the country where user is from I want him to see /en/products or /pl/produkty.

I managed to implement culture as part of the url, like /en/...., and user can also change default language by clicking a button on the website. However, I have no idea how to localize whole urls. I don't want to put hundreds of urls in Startup.cs (MapRoute). I need a better solution, which is working automatically behind the scenes.

If someone change directly the url (ex. en/products) and put pl instead of en, I want him/her to be redirected to pl/produkty automatically.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 4):

here's a very good ressource here:
[Asp.Net core Localization deep dive](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive)

Precisely here's what you're looking for:

```
 IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fi-FI"),
};
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, requestProvider);

app.UseRouter(routes =>
{
    routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=en-US}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
    {
        subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
        {
            mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The @Julien's answer is not helping.

The question is asking for localization of route/urls:

/en/products
/pl/produkty.
There is the solution: https://github.com/haestflod/asp.net-core-mvc-localized-routing

The guide: https://saaratrix.blogspot.com/2017/12/localized-routing-aspnet-core-mvc-2.html